# Chrome erases data at saving

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am creating a form for enrolment in a school using HTML and javascript. The idea is that students open the web page from a local server (it is not on the internet) and it is not submited but  they save it locally as a web page (after completing the form).
The problem is that chrome erases all field values at saving, whereas firefox or edge keep them, but chrome is the prefered browser in the school.
My question is: Is there a way to force chrome to keep input values when saving locally? I know there is the option of saving as a PDF (which keeps the data) but then the form is not editable any more.
There is a button in the page that changes the document title to students' name that they have to press before saving. Way of saving the file? Browser options->more tools--> save page as.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean all input values vanish when clicking on submit?

Comment: Can u tell me how u are saving the filled forms exactly?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific and elaborate the problem that you are facing, and if you have written a code then please do share here. Keep it minimal and self explainable.

Comment: Students don't submit the form. There is no submit button. Everything is done offline. they just fill in the input fields with the required information (name, address, email, telephone, etc.) and then they save the form as web page using the browser options on the local storages using their name as file name. when you open the file, everything is gone. Same procedure everything is kept in firefox. I wanted to know if there is a workaround. that happens with every form no matter the specific code. You can try it.

Comment: Why are you storing a html page off line? Why don't you just use word? This is a very strange implementation. Your question (and the comment hasn't really helped) doesn't make a lot of sense. You can't save a web page with it's input....it's a web page. That's not how the internet works

Comment: Liam, thanks for answering. I am using html format so that javascript can revise the information filled in by student, copy information which is asked several times within the form, calculate students' age from their date of birth and adding new fields if they are under a certain age, using different input types, it is quite a complex form for using word. Any way I see there is not a easy answer as to why google chrome behaves like this.

Comment: Code Ninja, should the code I've written be as simple and self-explainable as to meet your comprehension skills?, well, if so that'll be hard!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the localstorage which each and every browser supports

[local storage tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Or you can use file based data system. Just store the data into files which browser can use easily.

If you want to build a standard application then deploy one database on the local server of that school which will be centralised and whenever student will submit the data, you can send the data directly to that running server.

Comment: Thanks for answering, finally someone seems to have understood the question!

Comment: I think that saving to local storage function would be no good, as it is saved on each individual computer, and during school year hundreds of these forms will be filled in from say around 20 different computers in the school, and they are opened and saved, from a local server, file based data system seems to me a better option, do you have more info about how to do it?,using firefox to open and save files could be an option in the meantime.

Comment: Since file will be creating on the local system only so at the end you have to introduce the local server running on some machine. So you can do one thing. Just take one system and use that as server that will be a local server for your school only(No one can access that from outside world) and deploy some database or file based system on this system.

Comment: Now take the IP of this system and write some application which can send the data to this local server but for this each and every computer must have internet connection i hope if they are not connected with LAN if they are already connected with LAN then no need to internet i guess. 
Hope you got your answer.

Comment: Please give the vote up and accept the answer if you are okay with the suggestions provided by me.

Comment: Maybe I should elaborate on the problem, those documents are stored in a local drive, which can only be accesed by logging into a windows user account (or linux in some cases), the form changes dinamically based on users’ choices, for example if they choose to study French, choices are shown for French, there’s no submit button, at the end of the form, there’s an input type button which runs a javascript that checks if all required fields have been completed and alerts otherwise among other things

Comment: changes the page title to students names and finally opens a window.print (), after printing students sign a few times and document is saved as PDF in the local drive. The problem is that the PDF is not editable if, say, a student changes their address, so we’re considering saving as HTML, but, of course, keeping inputs is important.

Comment: Of course, building a database system is probably the best option on the long run, but that’s time-consuming and maybe not that necessary for present needs, protection of personal data is a concern for local educational authorities, so no way could the whole thing go online, and yes all the computers in the school have LAN and internet connection. We’re not cut off from the outside world.

Comment: Okay. Then just try to use the file system. Write an application which can store the data into file and take the end point from that application. Deploy that application on local server. That's all you can do i guess.

Answer (score 0):

A simple code to answer my question could go like this:

```js
function changeHTML (){
var mytext=document.getElementById ("mytext");
var askName=document.getElementById ("askName");
mytext.innerHTML="<input type='text' value='"+askName.value+"'/>";
}
```

```html
Name:<span id="mytext"><input type="text" id="askName" />
</span> 
<br/><br/>
<input type="button" onclick="changeHTML ()" value="save"  />
```